# Pair production from photons

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter, pair-production

Given the following events are simultaneous can multiple photons "add" together to give the energy required to produce a positron, electron pair?

$$ h\nu = m_e c^2 \gamma(v_1) + m_e c^2 \gamma(v_2) $$

This equation seems to suggest if I had more photons it WOULD be able to produce the energy of ~1Mev for electron and positron production.

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron

Comment: I've already seen this Wikipedia, but it says only two gamma rays can be used

Comment: At least two photons is sufficient. You cannot use one on-shell photon to create an e+ e- pair, but either on off-shell photon or more than one photon can do it.

Comment: In the case of lower energy photon

Comment: *photons, if lower momentum was consequential, would particles still form? v≠0, so mass decreases but the momentum must approach that of the constituent photons. This agrees with debroglies description of a particle. Interesting